# Raspberry Pi 2 + Hyundai W220d = red tint or blue is missing

Tags: hdmi, mate

this is my first post here and I'm kind of new on linux. I have a Raspberry Pi 2 on ubuntu mate with a Hyundai W220d screen.

The exact config (Raspberry Pi 2 on ubuntu mate with the same HDMI wire) with a different screen works without trouble
The exact screen with the same HDMI wire and a different config works without trouble

The OSD of the screen is correctly displayed.

The problem is a red tint on screen it's kind of like the blue or green is missing. I found a lot of similar posts but with a green tint. I tried several things in the config.txt, each time I edited and rebooted it was getting worse. I don't think it's a hardware issue, I think it's a config issue.
help !!!

Comment: This may be able to attract more attention / useful answers on [raspberrypi.se].